# I need help (with def) print out some alphabet

Tags: python, function

currently I faced issue with python code

I have two questions relate with "def" code.

1)
I need to print out 6 alphabet which is "K,E,Y,S,N,O"

slimier like under sample

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLh2w.png)

2)
how can I print out this alphabet if user typing one word like "KEY" then print out *mark with KEY
or If user typing "BED" then print out "E"only because we only have alphabet with K,E,Y,S,N,O

if can anyone help me with this two questions? I appreciate that

Thanks

Comment: I would create 2-dimensional list (list with lists for rows) to put `*` in correct places `(x,y)` (or rather `(y,x)`) and later I would display this list using `join()` to conver every row to string.

Comment: You can use string `"BED"` like list and work with every char separatelly `for char in word:` and then you can use `if/else` to check if `char` is in your list `["K","E","Y","S","N","O"]` to skip chars different then `E`. It is `filtering`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Question 1` need work with 2-dimensional list (list with lists for rows) and I skip this problem.

---

As for `Question 2` you can filter chars in word.

You can treat string `"BED"` as list of chars (even without using `list("BED")`) and you can use it in `for`-loop to check every char with list `["K","E","Y","S","N","O"]` (or `"KEYSNO"`) and skip chars `"B"` and `"D"`

```py
#my_chars = "KEYSNO"  # also works
my_chars = ["K","E","Y","S","N","O"]

word = "BED"

for char in word:
    if char in my_chars:
        print(char, "- OK")
    else:
        print(char, "- unknown")
```

Result:

```
B - unknown
E - OK
D - unknown
```

This way you can create new list to keep only correct chars

```
my_chars = ["K","E","Y","S","N","O"]

word = "BED"

filtered_chars = []        

for char in word:
    if char in my_chars:
        filtered_chars.append(char)

print(filtered_chars)
```

Result:

```
['E']
```

In Python you can write it even shorter using `list comprehension`

```
filtered_chars = [char for char in word if char in my_chars]
```

Eventually you can write it with function `filter()` like

```
filtered_chars = list(filter(lambda char: char in my_chars, word))
```

Comment: Thank you sir. it is really helpful to me.

Comment: but I have one more question, my_chars = ["K","E","Y","S"] and word = "KEY" how to print out KEY? because it is include 3 alphabet from my chars list and it is case insensitive (K or k, E or e, Y or y, S or S)

Comment: if you ask how to print it using `*` then it is more complex problem beacuse it needs chars aready converted to 2D arrays/lists with `*` and spaces, and later it needs to create new 2D array/list for word, and copy `*` from one array to other array in correct places.

Comment: if you ask how to filter chars is case insensitive then you can use `my_chars = ["K","E","Y","S", "k", "e", "y", "s"] ` or use `str.upper()` to convert chars to upper durring filtration - `word = word.upper()` or `if char.upper() in my_chars:`